# how to implement "Duplicate ssh channel"(Xshell) in Linux?

Tags: linux, ssh

Xshell has a function:"Duplicate ssh channel".
Is there a resemble function in openssh or other tools in Linux?

"Duplicate ssh channel":

1. ssh xx.yy.zz # inputs username:passwd
2. "Duplicate ssh channel" -> Xshell opens a new terminal without username:passwd

so, we could get many terminals on the xx.yy.zz, but input username:passwd only once.

Comment: maybe these would help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel or http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2010/02/ssh-controlmaster-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/ good luck.